# printing a string of a combination of different parts of the alphabet (python)

Tags: python

I want to print this string: `bcdefgihjklmnopqrstztsrqponmlkjhigfedcb`
I have already established that this string consists of three parts:

- b to t
- z
- t to b

What I have so far is just the first part:

```
for i in range (ord('b'), ord('t')+1):
    print chr(i),
```

But I really don't know how to add in the other two parts.

Can someone explain to me how I should tackle this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just print the string as a literal? Why the need to generate the output?

Comment: I'm not allowed to do so

Comment: And you could just use slicing on [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase) if you don't want to type those characters out. `[::-1]` gives you a reversed string (just add start and end): `from string import ascii_lowercase as letters; letters[1:20] + letters[-1] + letters[19:0:-1]`.

Comment: So what *are* you allowed to do? Please be specific in your question.

Comment: Printing the string as a literal isn't allowed. Though the second option u gave is. I can work it out from here I guess, thanks!

Comment: @RBC1994  can you print out `z` manually?

Comment: Btw, is it on purpose that `i` and `h` are reversed comparing the string to your definition? The string you gave us has `gihj` and not `ghij`. Same for the part where it's reversed.

Comment: oh shoot, I did make a typo after all :( Yes they are supposed to be the same but reversed. And z can't be printed out manually.

Answer (score 0):

Using a range with negative step value you can create the reverse list. Then concatenate the forward, the one element list for z and the reverse list using the shorthand '+' notation. Use list comprehension to convert the ascii indexes to the respective characters and finally join the resulting list using the empty string "".

```
ord_b = ord('b')
ord_t = ord('t')
ord_z = ord('z')
result = "".join([chr(i) for i in range(ord_b, ord_t+1) + [ord_z] + range(ord_t, ord_b-1, -1)])
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the trick.

```
x = [chr(i) for i in range (ord('b'), ord('t')+1)]
y = x[:]
y.reverse()
result = ''.join(x + ['z'] + y)
print(result)
```